# Regex not finding match - difference between .find() and .matches() at fault?

Tags: java, regex

Some background before the code - I maintain a system that is essentially an automated SFTP solution that polls a remote server, and pulls down some files to our side when it finds files in a certain directory that match a list of approved regex patterns.

Yesterday, some new files started appearing, and despite having a seemingly valid pattern in the table, were not being matched as files to look at.

Here is an example of a pattern that was, and still is, working fine in the system, along with an example file we have received that matches it (PickUp is the directory where all the file polling happens):

```
/PickUp/(?<foreignid>\\d{9})/rhinoceros\\d{9}\\d{8}.txt

/PickUp/123456789/rhinoceros98765432120201110.txt
```

Here is a new one that does not:

```
/PickUp/(?<foreignid>\\d{9})_\\d{8}_\\d{10}.zip

/PickUp/123456789_20201110_1234567890.zip
```

Below is the part of the function doing the matching:

```
int numMatches = 0;
for (PatternItem item : patternItems)
{
    matcher = item.getPattern().matcher(fileFound);
    if (matcher.find())
    {
        successfulMatch = matcher.group("foreignid");
        numMatches++;
    }
}

if (numMatches == 1)
{
    //download the file in here
}
else if (numMatches > 1)
{
    logger.error("More than one match found for file: " + fileFound + " - regex may be too permissive.");
    return "UNKNOWN_MULTI_MATCH";
}
else
{
    logger.error("Could not find match for file: " + fileFound);
    return "UNKNOWN_NO_MATCH";
}
```

I have validated that the pattern does match the file, and that the correct pattern is included in the pattern list. **My question is, is it possible the error is a result of using `matcher.find()` instead of `matcher.matches()`?** It seems like from my reading of other answers that `matches()` is for full matches, while `find()` does partial matches. Should I, in fact, be using `matches()` for my use case?

If so, why has this yet to break for any other patterns, all of which are similar to the working ones shown above? The only difference here, is that this is the first .zip file, and also the first time the foreignid group does not represent a subfolder that contains the file itself - it's just part of the name.

Thanks in advance for any help/clarity provided.

Comment: More context is needed. Can you set up a minimal runnable example where this problem occurs?

Comment: My guess is that the actual characters are not what you think they are. For example there are different forward slash characters that have different unicode code points but look the same including [division slash](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2215) and [fraction slash](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2044/index.htm). Or there may be non-printing characters like [left-to-right isolate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Unicode_Bidrectional_Text_Algorithm).

Comment: @xehpuk It's difficult to do that for demonstration here because the system pivots around a DynamoDB table with a GSI where the patterns live. You can run a Hello World here though to see that those patterns and files will match: https://pastebin.com/gEwAvzk3

Answer (score 0):

The problem is neither.

I modified your code as follows (in order for me to run it on my machine):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    String regex = "/PickUp/(?<foreignid>\\d{9})/rhinoceros\\d{9}\\d{8}.txt";
    String input = "/PickUp/123456789/rhinoceros98765432120201110.txt";
    // String regex = "/PickUp/(?<foreignid>\\d{9})_\\d{8}_\\d{10}.zip";
    // String input = "/PickUp/123456789_20201110_1234567890.zip";
    
    
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.groupCount());
    } else {
        System.err.println("No match");
    }
}
```

Regardless of which one you use `find()` or `matches()`, your inputs will match one group only, as shown by `groupCount()`. Your problem seems to be the differences in patterns. Your `/PickUp/(?<foreignid>\\d{9})/rhinoceros\\d{9}\\d{8}.txt` is matching the subdirectory under `PickUp` and not the file name. The bottom pattern doesn't use the first number group as a subdirectory. Instead, it uses it as part of the file name; and matches the first series of numbers only.

I am not sure if this is by design, but the problem are the patterns themselves; especially the use of "lookahead" (using the question mark inside parentheses).

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. The goal is to match the pattern, then extract the group, which is useful in file processing. In the affirmative case (the rhinoceros file/pattern), a match is made, then the foreignid group is saved and used in processing. In the problem case, a match is never made at all, even though it should be by my testing of simply the pattern against the input. I'm wondering if this is due to some behaviour of find() vs matches() considering I loop all patterns against the input using the same matcher.

Comment: @Rome_Leader There are differences between the two methods, but not for the inputs you provided. Run the code above a check for yourself. I don't think you are doing a correct comparison.